# Returning a Promise of a Promise in Typescript doesn't compile

Tags: typescript, promise

There's a lot going on in this problem so it's easiest if I jump into the code!

Consider these interfaces, which described objects in my database:

```
interface Owner {
  id: string
}

interface MyEntity {
  id: string
  owner: Owner
}
```

And these interfaces, which describes the results of queries to get these objects with a fluid API:

```
interface OwnerPromise extends Promise<Owner> {
  id: () => Promise<string>
}

interface MyEntityPromise extends Promise<MyEntity | null> {
  id: () => Promise<string>
  owner: <T = OwnerPromise>() => T
}
```

I have hundreds of these interfaces (generated by my ORM, and all have an `owner` property) and want to genericise my data access code to filter out anything that belongs to the wrong owner. I've made this interface, which can describe any of these query results very simply:

```
interface NullablePromiseWithOwner extends Promise<TEntity | null> {
  owner: <T = OwnerPromise>() => T
}
```

I've then written this function which I was hoping would mean I could easily check that the result of the query is owned by the correct person, while preserving the nice fluid API for accessing properties on these entities `*`

```
async function checkEntityOwnership<T, U extends NullablePromiseWithOwner<T>, TWhere>(f: (where: TWhere) => U, where: TWhere, currentOwnerId): Promise<U> {
  const owner = await f(where).owner();
  if (owner.id === currentOwnerId) return new Promise<U>(res => res(f(where)));
  throw new Error(); // You can't have something owned by something else!
}
```

VSCode Intellisense thinks this is fine, however when I try to compile it, I get the error `Type 'T' is not asssignable to type 'U'` and I'm not sure why. I **think** the compiler trying to unpack the double nested Promises, as Intellisense tells me that the return type of this function is Promise, but I've never seen anything in the documentation to suggest it would do this.

---

`*` Yes, there are other ways to solve this problem but in a big project I want to give developers as few opportunities as possible to write bad code!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not immediately sure what's wrong that's causing the actual error, but you shouldn't use `new Promise<U>(res => res(f(where)));`...ever. If `f(where)` returns a promise (and it does), just use that promise directly. If it didn't, or it *might* or might not, you'd use `Promise.resolve(f(where))` **except** when doing `await` or `return` in an `async` function, in which case you'd just use `await f(where)` or `return f(where)`. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Also, is it really correct in terms of your program logic to call `f(where)` twice when the owners match? Rather than just once?

Comment: The problem is that `f(where)` doesn't have a return type of `Promise<TEntity>`, but a return type of `U` where `U` extends  `NullablePromiseWithOwner<TEntity>`. And while that is technically a promise and I would love to make the return type of `checkEntityOwnership` U, the compiler won't allow an `async` method to return anything other than `Promise<T>`